# XSLT passing for each result to another template

Tags: xslt, foreach, parameters

I would like to pass a for each loop as a parameter to another template

```
<xsl:template name="dataTableGroup">
        <xsl:call-template name="test">
            <xsl:with-param name="pContent1">
                    <xsl:for-each
                        select="NewDataSet/Table[generate-id() = generate-id(key('countryKey', concat(Unit, ReportingBusUnitDesc)))]">

                        <tr>
                            <td class="columnTextRight">
                                <xsl:value-of select="ReportingBusUnitDesc"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>                
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>


    </xsl:template>
```

and use it here

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:param name="pContent1"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$pContent1">

    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:template>
```

but instead of nodes I get only values. Idealy I would like to have it work with xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an XSLT 1.0 processor then the parameter value is a result tree fragment so you need to use a processor specific extension function like `exsl:node-set` (http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) first to convert it into a node set e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:param name="pContent1"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($pContent1)/tr" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">

    </xsl:for-each>   
</xsl:template>
```

Node that doing a copy of a result tree fragment is possible without using any extension e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="$pContent1"/>` should do.

Also for the completeness of the example I have declared the namespace for the extension function on the `xsl:for-each` element, normally you would put it on the stylesheet's root element `xsl:stylesheet/transform` and additionally use `exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"` to ensure the namespace doesn't occur on any result elements.

With an XSLT 2 or 3 processor you shouldn't have any problems to use the variable directly as a fragment node containing your `tr` elements.